# Losing equations numbering when I render quarto document to word

Tags: equation, quarto

I am losing equations numbering when I render quarto documents to word. This is what I have in my YAML metadata:

```
---
title: XXX
#author: "wananchi"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
format:
  docx:
    fontfamily: libertinus
    fontsize: 11pt
    spacing: double
    toc: false
    number-sections: true
editor: visual
bibliography: citations.bib
csl: apa.csl
---
```

And this is an example of one of my equations:

```
$$
ES_{w,t} = \varepsilon_wEP_{w,t}\tag{1}
$$
```

What could be the issue? I don't experience the problem when I render to pdf.

I tried using the code I specified above and seems like it's not working.

Comment: I do not see anything pertainign towards 'rstudio' or 'r-markdown' in your question - why tag those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation numbering with `\tag` works for pdf output format, because `\tag` is a latex command, and with the help of [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/), `\tag` also works for html output format, But it does not works for word document.

Therefore, instead of using `\tag`, use `#eq-` label immediately after an equation to not only enable equation numbering for this equation but also make it cross referencable and it will work across different formats. Read [this section](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/cross-references.html#equations) from Quarto docs for a detailed example.

```
---
title: XXX
author: "wananchi"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
format:
  docx:
    fontfamily: libertinus
    fontsize: 11pt
    toc: false
    number-sections: true
# editor: visual
# bibliography: citations.bib
# csl: apa.csl
---

$$
ES_{w,t} = \varepsilon_wEP_{w,t}\
$${#eq-test}
```

---

[image: word output with equation numbering]

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  This is working but the numbering isn't aligned. Do you have any tips on how the numbering can be aligned at the margin ?

Comment: @wananchi, No I am not sure how to do that. Sorry : (

Answer (score 0):

With my quarto extension [mathjax3eqno](https://github.com/ute/mathjax3eqno), you can use mathjax capabilities also within html, but unfortunately not for books, because these would require keeping track of labelled equations across several rendered files. It is not working for word format, either.

If you want to use `\tag` within a single document that you only plan to render as html or pdf, add the extension, and you should be good to go as long as you use latex commands to refer to equations.

```
---
filters: [mathjax3eqno]
number-sections: true
---
# First Section
First equation
$$
   \lim_{n\to\infty} \exp(n) = \infty
$${#eq-toinf}

And another one:
$$
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \tag{$\ast$}
  \label{eq-py}
$$

# Second Section
Refer to \eqref{eq-toinf} and solve
\begin{equation}
  e = mc^2
\end{equation}
Then ponder about \eqref{eq-py}
```

Rendered to html would become

[image: rendered as html]